# Can we configure /ignoreUrlParams for a specific url?

Tags: apache, caching, aem, dispatcher

I have a requirement to cache

```
/etc/clientcontext/default/content/jcr:content/stores.init.js?path=xxxxx
```

But I am using url parameter "path" for some other urls also so cannot use /ignoreUrlParams.

Is there any way to use /ignoreUrlParams for specific url?or Is there any different way to solve this problem?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If possible would be good to have different query parameter for that specific case.

I think it's not possible to achieve something like that, it's seems that patterns for glob properties in /ignoreUrlParams don't work.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html?lang=en#designing-patterns-for-glob-properties